# Cannot set Apple ID on MacBook?

Tags: apple-id

It seems to me I'm not able to add my Apple ID to my MacBook, which would be handy if I ever needed to reset my password online for example. There's supposed to be a Set Apple ID section here according to my Google searches, but there isn't. Is there anything I need to do to be able to add the Apple ID? Curiously enough, I am able to see the device under iCloud's find my device.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your username, in the current user list, and select "Advance Options", from there you can change/add your Apple ID.